# How to count members belonging to a certain role in Discord.js bot?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to implement a function which messages the count of users assigned to a certain role.
A few months ago this worked flawlessly, but after a certain update it just stopped working correctly.

```
let count = message.guild.members.filter(m => m.roles.find(r => r.name === roleName)).size;
message.channel.send(user + " Count of users in " + roleName + ": "+count);
```

My code now looks like this:

```
let count = message.guild.members.cache.filter(m => m.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === roleName)).size; //These commands are in a module export, message is an object passed as an argument into it
message.channel.send(user + " Count of users in " + roleName + ": "+count);
```

Easy to say it doesn't work and it usually returns count of users that recently messaged or interacted with the bot. I tried using various `.fetch()` but they just return:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [GUILD_MEMBERS_TIMEOUT]: Members didn't arrive in time

...or something similair.
I tried `guild.members.fetch()`/`guild.fetch()` and such. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable the `SERVER MEMBERS INTENT` in your application.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to fetch all users or enable server members intent for such a feature.

You can send `GET` request to `https://discord.com/api/v8/guilds/<guildID>/roles/member-counts` endpoint.

This will return a response like this:

```
{
    "538088986342719490": 1,
    "593404972922830848": 2,
    ...
    // "roleID": memberCount,
}
```

Comment: This endpoint doesn't work with bot tokens or bearer tokens.

Comment: Yeah sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

In Discord.js v13 + The Syntax is:

```
const Guild = message.guild;
let Rolecount = Guild.members.cache.filter(m => m.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'RoleNameHere')).size;
```